# Unreproducible validation fail when opening URLs via Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync()

Tags: office-js, office-addins, office-store

We have had validation fail report from the Microsoft validation team for our Word add-in. The fail was for '..missing or placeholder elements or otherwise appears unfinished.'

The offending elements simply launch a URL via Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(). There are no conditions on any of these. There are 2 elements which are not highlighted as failing, which use exactly the same method.

We have tested this add-in on Windows 7 & IE11, Word 2013, Word 2016, O365 Word on Edge, Word on Mac - everything. It just works for us.

The fail report does not tell us the platform that failed. Though we have a video, the platform isn't clear there either. We have re-tested on every platform and it just works.

How do we find out the platform that the tester used? We can't fix what we can't reproduce. With all of the delays in validation runs we just can't afford to spin wheels guessing.

More detail requested : The failure was from the Microsoft validation team for our Word add-in. I don't know all the steps that were taken because they did not provide detail.

At the very least, they would have had to have opened the add-in amd authenticated with our application. At this point they do see the sidebar elements (buttons) which they click to open a modal in Word.

All we can see in the video is that nothing happens when they click. It does for when we test, every time. But the report does not give us any information about which version of Word this happens in, or if there were any steps taken before the fail.

The validation email gives this as a way to contact the validation team, which is what I am trying to do.

Comment: Please provide some background information. Who is seeing this error and where do they see it? What steps lead up to it? Is this from a report that you received from the store? What do you mean by "element"?

Comment: The failure was from the Microsoft validation team for our Word add-in. I don't know what steps were taken because they did not provide detail. At the very least, they would have had to have opened the add-in, authenticated with our application, at which point they see the sidebar elements (buttons) which they click to open a modal in Word. All we can see in the video is that nothing happens when they click. It does for when we test, every time.

Comment: I'm making an inquiry internally in Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst we are unable to comment on individual offers, if there was not any specific platforms mentioned in the report it would generally mean that the issue was seen on all platforms.

For assistance on Microsoft Commercial Marketplace, Azure Marketplace, AppSource and Certification issues, please sign-in to Marketplace Publisher Support at https://aka.ms/marketplacepublishersupport 
    Browse topics
    Category: Commercial Marketplace
    Topic: Certification issue
Next step: Review solution